# Is there a way to move between splitted windows using a shortcut or maybe a shortcut plugin in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, split, keyboard-shortcuts, panel, move

I'm using Apache Netbeans 11.1. I was wondering if there is a way to move between splitted views for a java class. 
Im using the shortcut (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>) to create a clone and make an horizontal split  for some java class and be able to work on two diferents parts of the file at the same time, but I can't find a a hotkey on the available shorcut's list in Netbeans (`Tools → Options → Keymap`) to move easely between this two panels. Is there a way to move with the keyboard without point and click with the mouse?, maybe some plugin instead?

[splitted file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlxZ0.png)

I also would like to know if there is a way to move between splitted windows when I use drag and drop to work the same way as described before but with different files:

-> [dragging a file too make a splitted screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S71m1.png)

-> [final splitted screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocbtk.png)

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers.

Comment: Don't have a Netbeans installation at hand, but: CTRL+TAB does not work?

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for your answer. I recently tested the shortcut. It works great moving between differents files,  but if I try using It when I used  previously the (CTRL + SHIFT + H) or (CTRL + SHIFT + V) shortcuts to make a split view of the           same file (clone splitted view) it doesn't work.